# How does Linux allocate memory for the file cache?

Tags: linux, file, caching

**The problem:**

There are two components in our system, *A* and *B*. *A* processes requests and generates files from them; for each file it notifies *B* on file creation, and *B* reads the file. The file is expected to still be cached by OS and be read without accessing the hard drive. That's in theory. In reality, only the first 304,000 files are in the cache, the remaining files are not. Meanwhile, there is no shortage of physical memory - as *B* continues running and allocates memory for its needs, the resident page count grows (*B* logs memory stats from */proc/self/stat* - from the moment the file caching stops until the end of run the RSS increases by 13Gb).

If it can help answer my question, the files are mapped by *B*, not read, and *B* closes the file immediately after mapping.

**The questions:**

Does the OS (RedHat Linux) limit the number of cached files based on things other than the avaialble memory? Or does OS limit the file cache to some percentage of available memory, which is why there is still memory available to the applications when the cache limit is reached?

Is it possible, and how, to make OS cache all the files?

Comment: Maybe you could consider writing them to a RAM disk.  Or have *B* read a pipe of the data from *A* directly.

Comment: How did you conclude that there is no shortage of physical memory based on those observations? How much "free" memory does `free -g` show when it stops caching? (make sure to use `free -g` and not any other tool that may try to show "available" memory instead)

Comment: @Kingsley >  the data must be accessible for _B_ even after system reboot, or if _A_ or _B_ are restarted, so the data must be saved in real files.

Comment: @that-other-guy > I will test with _free -g_. Is reading RSS from _/proc/stat_ not a reliable measurement?

Comment: @me76 These are unrelated measurements